# How to count characters in buffer including spaces?

Tags: mode-line

I need to see, how many characters contains my text, as I type. I found this pages of Emacs Wiki: [Word count](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WordCount), and there is a solution very close to what I need: I used the second solution from this page (Show the number of words in the mode-line), because it shows the amount of characters too.

But it doesn't count spaces. Is there any solution, that will show amount of characters including spaces in mode-line? Ideally, with setting target amount of characters (but this is not necessary).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`mode-line-format`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/mode-line-format) variable already has that capability built-in, the following snippet should add that near the end of your mode-line.

```
(add-to-list 'global-mode-string '(" %i"))
```

From the Doc:

> %i -- print the size of the buffer.

Technically, this is the size in bytes, so it might not match
perfectly the number of chars depending on the encoding you use.

You can also try, `M-x size-indication-mode`.

---

If the number of bytes does not satisfy you, you can use the following
snippet, which may or may not cause lag as you type on very large
buffers.

```
(add-to-list 'global-mode-string
             '(:eval (format " %s"
                       (let ((tab-width 1))
                         (string-width (buffer-string))))))
```

Answer (score 27):

Alternatively, count words and characters including spaces in a selection:

```
M-x count-words-region
```

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is `M-=`. In spacemacs, `count-region` uses the keyboard shortcut `SPC x c` which is an alias for `count-words-region`

Answer (score 4):

Or you could simply <kbd>M-></kbd><kbd>C-x =</kbd>. The relevant info will appear in the minibuffer. (Commands used: `end-of-buffer` and `what-cursor-position`).

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have given you useful info, I think. You can put whatever you want in the mode-line, and one place to start is `size-indication-mode` and variable variable `mode-line-position`.

The other answers generally tell you the current buffer position relative to the *start of the buffer* (or the start of its current restriction, if it is narrowed).

Sometimes you might want the position relative to some other position.  For that, library [**`modeline-posn.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/modeline-posn.el) can help (see [Mode Line Position](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLinePosition)).

When the region is not active, it shows you the usual information (well, a bit better). But when it is active it shows you (in the mode-line) the **number of characters and lines in the selection** (region). So to see the current position relative to some other position, just use `C-SPC` to set the mark at one of the positions.  `C-x C-x` activates the region, which shows you its size in characters (and lines) in the mode-line.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you could just use `point-max` to get the number of characters in the buffer:

```
(defun count-chars ()
  (interactive)
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (message "%s characters" (1- (point-max)))))
```

Comment: It works, but this is not exactly what I want: I want to have number of character always before my eyes, while I'm typing, not getting it "on demand".

Comment: @Aglavra add it to your mode-line.

Comment: Ah.  You may want to try [`size-indication-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Optional-Mode-Line.html#Optional-Mode-Line), or modifying the [`mode-line-position`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html) variable instead, then.